# Does Rails have a method to construct src="foo.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;layout=standard"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems that we will need 2 methods, one is `CGI.escape` and the other might be `h` (unless we hardcode `&amp;`.

Is there a method that takes an array or hash of params, and compose it into this form?

```
src="foo.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;layout=standard"
```

It is for Rails 2.2.2, so if there is a method in Rails 2.x that can do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Object#to_query to do it, but I'm not certain if it is available in Rails 2.x. For example:

```
{
  :href => "http://example.com/",
  :layout => "standard"
}.to_query # => "layout=standard&href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F"
```

Comment: works on Rails 2.2.2, except it doesn't make the `&` as `&amp;`.  Previously I use `&` in other pages and they work fine, just except when it is to validate as HTML 4.01, where it wants `&amp;`

Comment: Alright, so in your HTML put an h() around it, that should fix it.